# How to hide table cell after choosing a drop down in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift5, tablecell

I have a problem here..
So, I am using cocoapods for dropdown and table view controller, 
and I want to hide the next cell if the dropdown says "Yes", and keep the next cell 
when I hit " No ".
How do I do that?
How do I hide the next section?

Here my code & visual image.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thankyou

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    DropDown.show()
    let choosen = DropDown.indexForSelectedRow

    if choosen == 0 {
        self.section2.isHidden = true 
    }

    else if choosen == 1 {
        self.section2.isHidden = false 
    }
}
```

[image: why it's so slow mo tho Lol]

Comment: what are section1 and section2 ? Outlets for tableCell?

Comment: try to create collapsible sections, quite a few tutorials are available online.

Comment: Put your button in section header and the cell to be removes keep them as cell, when you want to hide any section make that section's numberOfRows = 0

Comment: may be you can reload table view and set number of section when you hide and show

Comment: Your dropdown function in getting called on button tap . you set the specific section height 0  and reload table view

Answer (score 2):

Your dropdown function in getting called on button tap. You should use the delegate method of your dropdown function to know once user has chosen a value. Then inside that function you can hide unhide your cells.

Comment: Also you can save chosen value and according to this - reload tebleView with new dataSource, which includes section0 and section1 only.